# Can all summations be represented as recurrences?

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

I'm reading [Concrete Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics) and on chapter 2 they mentioned that sums and recurrences have and intimate relationship, can you switch between one and the other?

Comment: Too broad of a question.  Both “no” and “yes” could be justified. If $S_n =\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ then of course $S_{n+1}=S_n+x_{n+1}$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.